# Aurelia Custom Attribute with setAttribute method()

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia, custom-attributes

It seems Aurelia is not aware when I create and append an element in javascript and set a custom attribute (unless I am doing something wrong). For example,

```
const e = document.createElement('div');
e.setAttribute('custom-attr', 'some value');
body.appendChild(e);
```

Is there a way to make Aurelia aware of this custom attribute when it gets appended?

**A little background:** I am creating an app where the user can select their element type (e.g. input, select, checkbox etc.) and drag it around (the dragging is done in the custom attribute). I thought about creating a wrapper `<div custom-attr repeat.for="e of elements"></div>` and somehow render the elements array, but this seemed inefficient since the repeater will go through all the elements everytime I push a new one and I didn't not want to create a wrapper around something as simple as a text input that might be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to manually trigger the Aurelia's `enhance` method for it to register the custom attributes or anything Aurelia related really. And you also have to pass in a ViewResources object containing the custom attribute.

---

Since this isn't as straight forward as you might think, I'll explain it a bit.

The enhance method requires the following parameters for this scenario:

- Your HTML as plain text (string)
- The binding context (in our scenario, it's just `this`)
- A ViewResources object that has the required custom attribute

One way to get access to the ViewResources object that meets our requirements, is to `require` the custom attribute into your parent view and then use the parent view's `ViewResources`. To do that, `require` the view inside the parent view's HTML and then implement the `created(owningView, thisView)` callback in the controller. When it's fired, `thisView` will have a `resources` property, which is a ViewResources object that contains the `require`-d custom attribute.

Since I am HORRIBLE at explaining, please look into the example provided below.

---

Here is an example how to:

**app.js**

```
import { TemplatingEngine } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {
  static inject = [TemplatingEngine];

  message = 'Hello World!';

  constructor(templatingEngine, viewResources) {
    this._templatingEngine = templatingEngine;
  }

  created(owningView, thisView) {
    this._viewResources = thisView.resources;
  }

  bind() {
    this.createEnhanceAppend();
  }

  createEnhanceAppend() {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = "<h5 example.bind=\"message\"></h5>";
    this._templatingEngine.enhance({ element: span, bindingContext: this, resources: this._viewResources });
    this.view.appendChild(span);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./example-custom-attribute"></require>

  <div ref="view"></div>
</template>
```

---

**Gist.run:**

https://gist.run/?id=7b80d2498ed17bcb88f17b17c6f73fb9

---

**Additional resources**

Dwayne Charrington has written an excellent tutorial on this topic:

https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/01/enhancing-at-will-using-aurelias-templating-engine-enhance-api/

Comment: thanks for that resource, i was not aware of that. However, i could not get it to work with the custom attribute. I forked your gist to show you the attribute working when it is on the element and then it not working when i dynamically add it https://gist.run/?id=6216f60bcfc201074d81f6913d59c82c

Comment: so I found out that example will work if the attribute is under `globalResourses` and not in the `require` tag. not sure (yet) how to get it to work with the `require` tag

Comment: Maybe you would have to add it to the source code of the element? I know that you can provide a `viewResources: ViewResources` property to the enhance function, but I don't really know how to register resources to it.

Comment: same here. I was trying to play around with the `ViewResources` class to get it to work, but have not yet.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please see if this works for you as well. The new gist.run link is a working example, as well as is the code in the answer. :)

Comment: ahh I forgot about that second argument Aurelia provides to us, Thanks!