# Dynamically adding custom elements to DOM Aurelia

Tags: d3.js, aurelia

I am using d3.js in an Aurelia app, and I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically add custom Aurelia components and have them rendered properly, like so:

```
d3.select("#my-container")
    .append("my-custom-component")
    .attr("data.bind", "my-value");
```

Where `my-custom-component` is something like:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyCustomComponent {
    @bindable data;

    attached() {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

It appears in the DOM the way I would expect, but it never hits the `debugger` and doesn't render the actual component.  Is this possible?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034219/aurelia-custom-attribute-with-setattribute-method/42034422#42034422

Comment: You need to manually trigger the Aurelia's `enhance` method to tell Aurelia to propagate the custom element.